# What does the 'UN' stand for in UNNotification?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I noticed over the years that Apple has dropped prefixes such as 'NS' when using Swift.  Now as I'm going through a local notifications tutorial, I see that UIUserNotificationSettings has been deprecated and it asks that we use UNNotificationSettings instead.  I understand that 'NS' stood for Next Step so is there a correlation possibly that 'UN' stands for something?

Comment: **U** ser **N** otifications framework: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications.

Comment: Objective-C didn't have namespaces so in order to minimize conflicts they had to add prefixes to their framework classes. It was a mess but it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a general rule every item inside a framework takes it's name prefix

```
UIButton -> UIKit -> User Interface

AVAudioPlayer -> AVFoundation -> Audio Video

UNNotification -> UserNotifications - > User Notification
```

Answer (score 8):

Classes such as `UNNotificationSettings` and other `UNNotification...` classes are in the `UserNotifications` framework. So it seems the "UN" is for User Notifications.